# Error al construir Future selectImage(ImageSource imageSource) async

Tags: flutter

```
Future? selectImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: imageSource);
    if (pickedFile != null){
      imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    }
    Navigator.pop(context!);
    refresh!();
  }
```

Error en File(pickedFile.path)  - he argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

Comment: que package es ese? estás usando la última versión ? que tipo de dato retorna pickedFile.path?

Comment: exactamente la ultima version 
solo esta instanciado PickedFile? pickedFile;

Comment: no respondiste todo lo que pregunté :), ahí encontrarás la respuesta

Comment: Que tipo de variable es imageFile? String o List?